# How to solve this line integral problem?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, line-integrals

Let $f(z)$ be

$f(z) = \frac{2}{(z-1)^2} +\frac{3}{(z-1)}+\frac{\sin z}{e^{z}}$ ,

calculate

$I = \int_{|z|=5} f(z) dz$

---

I already use $\int \frac{dz}{(z-a)^n}=0$ and $\int \frac{dz}{z-a}=2 \pi i$

to solve $\frac{2}{(z-1)^2}$ and $\frac{3}{(z-1)}$ and know the answer are $0$ and $6 \pi i $,But I don't know how to calculate $\frac{\sin z}{e^{z}}$.

How to calculate $\frac{\sin z}{e^{z}}$??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose to use the [reidue theorem](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_des_r%C3%A9sidus):

$$\int_\gamma f(z) dz = 2i \pi \sum_{k=1}^n \mathrm{Res}(f, z_k)$$

In the circle defined by $|z| = 5$, you must look for the singularities you have. As your function is as sum of 3 other functions, we can apply the residue theorem to each of them separatly and then sum the results.

For the first term: double [pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeros_and_poles) at $z = 1$ (double because of the "$^2$"). Is it in the circle $|z| = 5$ ? Yes. Same idea for the second term: simple pole at the same point.

About the third term, let's look for the singularities:

$$e^z = 0 = \cos(z) + i \sin(z)$$

Their is **not value of $z$ such as the equation above is satisfied**. So the residue of this term is equal to $0$.

Note that I used an alternative method, and that yours (first Cauchy formula) also works. If you are not familiar with the residue theorem, use the [Cauchy Goursat theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) which is much easier to understand. It stands that for any analytical functions in your domain (here, $|z| \le 5$), its definite integral along your curve $\gamma$ will be equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\frac{\sin(z)}{e^z}(=e^{-z}\sin(z))$ is an entire function, its integral along any loop is equal to $0$.